# How to have multiple connections using postgresql

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I have currently worked on a web-scrape applications where I have multiple scripts (around 20-30 scripts) that needs to be connected to the database (PostgresSQL 11) for INSERT/SELECT/DELETE etc etc... I have found out that having one connections for each python script would be very resource intenstive (Total connection would be between 20-30 connections).

My first idea was to create a context manager where I open connection -> Commit -> Close connection everytime I want to do a query but I did find out this to be very slow and takes more resources than I should do.

example:

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

DATABASE_CONNECTION = {
    "host": configuration.path.database.environment,
    "database": configuration.postgresql.database,
    "user": configuration.postgresql.user,
    "password": configuration.postgresql.password,
}


class QuickConnection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ps_connection = psycopg2.connect(**DATABASE_CONNECTION)
        self.ps_cursor = self.ps_connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
        self.ps_connection.autocommit = True

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.ps_cursor

    def __exit__(self, err_type, err_value, traceback):
        if err_type and err_value:
            self.ps_connection.rollback()
        self.ps_cursor.close()
        self.ps_connection.close()
        return False
```

However my problem is that I would like to have better speed and to be efficient when using multiple scripts with each own have its own connection

My question is: How can I have multiple scripts with each connections to the postgresql database without it to be resource intenstive?

Comment: 20 to 30 open connections is generally not a problem unless they are all trying to do intensive activity at the same time.  Did you actually *experience* it being a problem, or are you just believing rumors?

Comment: @jjanes Believing the rumors. They are not doing any heavy at all. Mostly just SELECT queries as well. But that could be minutes or even hours before some script calls that query. So no. Nothing heavy